# VB.Net Array.Sort nullifying values

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I'm having some serious trouble with the Array.Sort functionality within my VB.net program. Everything within my code, including what is pasted here seems to function all the way through the loop (which is at the end of my code), including populating FinalDataArray with the information that I expect, **however** when I pass it to Array.Sort, then I end up with FinalDataArray having a null value at every index. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

The applicable portion of my code is as follows:

UPDATE: I've updated my code block to show the entire Sub from this program.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    frmMain.CurrentFigure = txtFigure.Text
    frmFigureViewer.Show()
    Dim ArrayUpperBound = FGCFigNo.Length
    FigureResult = Enumerable.Range(0, FGCFigNo.Length).Where(Function(f) FGCFigNo(f) = frmMain.CurrentFigure).ToArray
    frmFigureViewer.lblFGCfromFGCList.Text = FGCCode(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblTOPCurrentFigureTitle.Text = FGCTitle(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblTOPDisplayFigure.Text = FGCFigNo(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblCurrentSheet.Text = FGCSheetNo(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblFinalSheet.Text = FGCSheetNo(FigureResult(FigureResult.Length - 1))
    ArtResult = FGCArtID(FigureResult(frmFigureViewer.lblCurrentSheet.Text - 1))
    Dim JpgFilePath As String = "C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer" + "\" + Mid(ArtResult, 1, ArtResult.Length - 4) + ".jpg"
    If File.Exists(JpgFilePath) Then
        GoTo OnlyDisplay
    End If
    Dim SourceFile As String = ""
    Dim DestinationFile As String = ""
    Dim EpsFilePath As String = ARTFOLDER + "\" + ArtResult
    If Not Directory.Exists("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer") Then
        MkDir("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer")
    End If



    SourceFile = EpsFilePath
    DestinationFile = Mid(EpsFilePath, 1, Len(EpsFilePath) - 4) + " view.eps"
    FileCopy(SourceFile, DestinationFile)

    EpsFilePath = DestinationFile

    RunGS("-q", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER", "-sDEVICE=jpeg", _
      "-r600", "-dJPEGQ=100", "-dEPSCrop", "-dDownScaleFactor=0", "-dTextAlphaBits=4", "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4", _
      "-sPAPERSIZE=letter", "-sOutputFile=" & JpgFilePath, EpsFilePath)
    Kill(EpsFilePath) 'KILLS THE "...view.eps" temporary file in the working folder.

OnlyDisplay:

    frmFigureViewer.picMyJPEG.Image = Image.FromFile(JpgFilePath)

    Fig036Result = Enumerable.Range(0, FIGURENO.Length).Where(Function(f) FIGURENO(f) = frmMain.CurrentFigure).ToArray

    'BUILD DICTIONARY HERE'
    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim DictionaryFigureNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim DictionarySortPosition As Integer = 1
    Do Until DictionaryFigureNumber = 1000
        Dim DictionaryFigureLetterASCII As Integer = 65
        dict.Add(DictionaryFigureNumber, DictionarySortPosition)
        DictionarySortPosition = DictionarySortPosition + 1
        Do Until DictionaryFigureLetterASCII = 91

            dict.Add(DictionaryFigureNumber & Chr(DictionaryFigureLetterASCII), DictionarySortPosition)
            DictionarySortPosition = DictionarySortPosition + 1
            DictionaryFigureLetterASCII = DictionaryFigureLetterASCII + 1
        Loop
        DictionaryFigureNumber = DictionaryFigureNumber + 1
    Loop
    'END OF DICTIONARY BUILDING

    Dim TempLength = Fig036Result.GetLength(0)
    TempLength = TempLength - 1
    Dim CurrentPlace As Integer = 0
    Dim TempItemNo As String
    Dim ArrayString As String = ""
    Do Until CurrentPlace > TempLength

        Dim ArrayLocation As Integer = Fig036Result(CurrentPlace)
        TempItemNo = ITEMNO(ArrayLocation)
        TempSMR = SMnR(ArrayLocation)
        TempNSN = NSN(ArrayLocation)
        TempCAGE = CAGE(ArrayLocation)
        TempPartNum = PARTNUM(ArrayLocation)
        TempDescription = ITEMName(ArrayLocation)
        TempUOC = UOC(ArrayLocation)
        TempQTY = QTYFIG(ArrayLocation)
        TempIndvFGC = FGC(ArrayLocation)
        Dim TempValue As String = ""
        dict.TryGetValue(TempItemNo, TempValue)
        ArrayString = TempValue + "::" + TempItemNo + "|" + TempSMR + "|" + TempNSN + "|" + TempCAGE + "|" + TempPartNum + "|" + TempDescription + "|" + TempUOC + "|" + TempQTY + "|" + TempIndvFGC + "|"
        FinalDataArray(CurrentPlace) = ArrayString

        'FinalSortArray(CurrentPlace) = TempValue

        CurrentPlace = CurrentPlace + 1
    Loop
    Array.Sort(FinalDataArray)

End Sub
```

Update2: I've updated the looping portion of the code as follows:

```
Dim TempValue As String = ""
        dict.TryGetValue(TempItemNo, TempValue)
        ArrayString = TempItemNo + "|" + TempSMR + "|" + TempNSN + "|" + TempCAGE + "|" + TempPartNum + "|" + TempDescription + "|" + TempUOC + "|" + TempQTY + "|" + TempIndvFGC + "|"
        FinalDataArray(CurrentPlace) = ArrayString

        FinalSortArray(CurrentPlace) = TempValue

        CurrentPlace = CurrentPlace + 1
    Loop
    Array.Sort(FinalSortArray, FinalDataArray)
```

My new declaration for my two arrays are:

```
    Public FinalSortArray(50000) As Integer
Public FinalDataArray(50000) As String
```

Comment: That code will never work. You are not declaring `FinalDataArray` as an array, which you would be doing like this: `Public FinalDataArray() As String`. After that you need to specify the size of the array which you are not doing, so this line `FinalDataArray(CurrentPlace) = ArrayString` would cause a runtime error.

Comment: I don't believe that to be true Jeroen. I've changed the code to match what you are talking about and it still produces the same result. Let me reiterate that, as far as I can tell, there isn't anything wrong with my code within my Do Until loop. When I view the FinalDataArray contents PRIOR to the line Array.Sort(FinalDataArray) that everything is as I would expect it, the array filled with data. However once I move to the next line and the Array.Sort method is executed, then I end up with an array full of null values.

Comment: You have declared FinalDataArray but have not specified its size.  If you attempt to call `FinalDataArray(CurrentPlace)` you will get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.  Do you have FinalDataArray defined in more than one place?  Can you show a short but complete program that demonstrates the error?  The code as shown will produce an exception.

Comment: I can attempt to recreate the issue in a smaller application, or I can post the entirety of this Sub if that would be easier? I'm not sure I'm getting my point across though. I'm not having any issues with the FILLING of the array, all of that functions and fills with the data that I expect it to, using the loop I posted above. It's only once I go to actually SORT the filled array, with Array.Sort(FinalDataArray) , that I end up with null values in the array. There is no "error message" that pops up, it's just that the act of sorting the array fills the array with null values.

Comment: I've updated my code block to show the entirety of the sub from my program. Hopefully that will help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You have still not specified the size for FinalDataArray. Like I said in my first comment (as well as @ChrisDunaway after me), that will cause a runtime error. Regardless of you "not believing that to be true" :-) In the edited code you have in your question  the declaration of that array disappeared completely. There is no error handling in this sub, you are using GoTo... I don't know where to start.

Comment: Instead of creating arrays with 50K elements (which seems wasteful), why not simply use `List(of T)`? That way you don't have to specify how many elements you need upfront so you can't run out causing a costly redim. Having just enough elements will also get you away from the sorting towards the back of the array. Now fix that GoTo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have no idea how large the array really is, it's bigger than you expect and `Array.Sort` refills the array from the back... Consider:

```
Dim arr() As String
ReDim arr(10)
arr(0) = "Z"
arr(2) = "3"
arr(1) = "Boolean"
arr(5) = "Hello"
Array.Sort(arr)
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
  Debug.Print(arr(i))
Next
```

Even though I specified the size of the array as 11 and filled only 4 random spots with data, after the `Array.Sort` my data is sorted at the back of the array and only `arr(7)...arr(10)` contain data (in the proper order).

Comment: Good catch.  I think the OP can confirm this by showing the length of the array and the value of TempLength.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDunaway I had to try it to be reminded of this "odd" behavior... But you would have seen it straight away if you know how to properly use watches in VS.

Comment: What I didn't realize was that Array.Sort actually filled the array backwards when it was all said and done (in proper order as you said), so I wasn't looking at the end of the array to see that the values were there.

I was still having trouble getting the sort to work, until I realized that both of my arrays were declared as objects rather than as Integer and String like I need. I've also split TempValue away from the rest of the string into FinalSortArray and using an Array.Sort(Array,Array) to sort both.

Public FinalSortArray(50000) As Integer
    Public FinalDataArray(50000) As String